# Hibernate one-to-many relationship

Tags: hibernate

While iterating the data from one-to-may relationship in hibernate,the next record is not fetching, instead the first record printing twice if two records present in DB...

I just fetching the data from DB..

I haven't set data using Hibernate;

Comment: show us some code and output please

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at this.  Depending on your query construction, it is possible that you can return rows more than once.  This can be eliminated using result transformer.

```
Criteria criteria = ...
// Build your query
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY); // Ensure no duplicates
```

I have had to use this in several complex queries.